# Exceptions in COM

Tags: c++, exception, com

I'm writing an interface with COM code and I know that the only user of this interface is my own code (indirectly). If I throw an exception, can I catch it on the other side of the library that's in the middle? This is a termination condition so the world's most graceful cleanup isn't the biggest deal ever.

Comment: If you can make such guarantees then there's just no point in using COM.

Comment: @Hans Passant: The intermediate library expects COM. I personally have no need of COM.

Comment: Well, it certainly won't expect exceptions.

Comment: Just don't do it. Can you be sure that there won't be a marshaller between your caller and callee? If you need detailed error information, either use IErrorInfo, or an out parameter of your type/interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exceptions aren't allowed to flow across a COM interface boundary.  Because there is no binary contract for C++ exceptions, COM cannot marshal them from one thread to another.  This might not be a huge issue now but it may be a problem later on if you decide to change the threading model of your COM object.

Also, what happens if you decide that you want to rewrite the front end of your application in C# (or Delphi or whatever)?  COM HRESULTS are understood by the various COM interop frameworks but C++ exceptions aren't (no binary contract for C++ exceptions).

Comment: +1 too add that the 'proper' way to provide error information across the COM boundary is to implement `IErrorInfo` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221233.aspx. Most client components, including C++ COM support classes like `_com_ptr_t` will leverage this info and raise exceptions with detailed information.

Comment: I'd like to point out that it is also often hard to track down errors like these. I have seen scenarios ranging from processes just going down in flames, to obscure E_xxx return codes indicating there was an error during the marshalling. Not playing by the COM rules on a COM arena is asking for a world of paine...

Comment: +1. Specifically if a C++ exception reaches to C# code the C# code crashes big time.

Comment: @Larry: We're currently struggling with SEH behavior on the COM boundary (https://stackoverflow.com/q/72460562/321013) Maybe you could share your opinion on this one.