# COMGLB_EXCEPTION_DONOT_HANDLE_ANY does not always work for unhandled C++ exceptions

Tags: windows, visual-c++, com, rpc, seh

### TL;DR

(Visual Studio 2019, Windows 10 (so far tested on 1809LTSC, because this is my dev machine)

- We have an out-of-process COM server
- We set `COMGLB_EXCEPTION_DONOT_HANDLE_ANY`
- "Fatal" SEH exceptions are handled OK.
- "Non-Fatal" SEH exceptions, among these C++ excpetions, are **randomly** swallowed or handled by the COM/RPC runtime stack.

Does [`COMGLB_EXCEPTION_DONOT_HANDLE` **`_ANY`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-iglobaloptions) work reliably? Are there any additional settings?

### Neccessary Background

When using [COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/component-object-model--com--portal), the RPC layer will catch (and possibly swallow) all [Structured SEH Exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp?view=msvc-170) (which include C++ exceptions). [Raymond explains this very well](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110120-00/?p=11713):

> Historically, COM placed a giant try/except around your server’s
> methods. If your server encountered what would normally be an
> unhandled exception, the giant try/except would catch it and turn it
> into the error RPC_E_SERVERFAULT. It then marked the exception as
> handled, so that the server remained running ... Mind you, this was
> actually a disservice

Now there is a supposed solution, namely [`IGlobalOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-iglobaloptions) with setting COMGLB_EXCEPTION_DONOT_HANDLE_ANY.

This is *supposed* to (to quote The Old New):

> ... then go ahead and let the process crash.” In Windows 7, you can
> ask for the even stronger COMGLB_EXCEPTION_DONOT_HANDLE_ANY, which
> means “Don’t even try to catch ‘nonfatal’ exceptions.”

You can even find this recommendation in the docs:

> It's important for applications that detect crashes and other
> exceptions that might be generated while executing inbound COM calls,
> ... to set COMGLB_EXCEPTION_HANDLING to COMGLB_EXCEPTION_DONOT_HANDLE
> to disable COM behavior of catching exceptions.

And the option is explained as:

> `COMGLB_EXCEPTION_DONOT_HANDLE_ANY`:
>
> - When set and a fatal exception
>   occurs in a COM method, this causes the COM runtime to not handle the
>   exception. (caveat A)
> - When set and a non-fatal exception occurs in a COM method, this causes
>   the COM runtime to create a Windows Error Reporting (WER) dump and
>   terminate the process. Supported in Windows 7 and later. (caveat B)

#### And here's the thing

**Neither** of the above two statements is really accurate, but specifically for any *non fatal* exception, which C++ exceptions are, we get **random** behavior:

I have set up [a simple client / server COM Test Program](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8679/Building-a-LOCAL-COM-Server-and-Client-A-Step-by-S) in VS2019 and intentionally generate an unhandled C++ exception: There are two modes at runtime, seemingly at random:

- Server is terminated by the COM/RPC stack and we get an ID 1000 entry in the event log with the exceptioncode `0xe06d7363` (and a WER dump is written). The *client* gets 0x800706BE HRESULT in this case.

  - This is the advertised behavior.
- Starting the client -> server a second (or third, ...) time, the C++ Exception DOES NOT terminate the server, and the client gets `0xe06d7363` as HRESULT for its server call. No event log entry written!

For those "fatal" SEH exceptions the termination happens reliably; but not for the non-fatal ones.

What is going on here?

Comment: I don't reproduce. For me the option works as expected, each time you start a server configured with COMGLB_EXCEPTION_DONOT_HANDLE_ANY and throw for example a C++ exception (0xe06d7363), the server terminates (and the client receives 0x800706BE). Note depending on your local config, the server throwing may start a debugger or other stuff instead of terminating immediatly. Or please provide a complete reproduction example. IGlobalOptions must be set right after server's CoInitialize call.

Comment: @SimonMourier - thanks for trying. Yeah, maybe it is a environmental issue. I don't see any debugger attaching - the server just continues to run normally. But given it's flaky on my side, it would appear natural to assume that there are cases like yours where it's simply working. The purpose of the question really is to gauge whether I'm missing something obvious with the setup.